# Having Trouble rendering React Resume & Portfolio components - Header, Footer, & Profile components are all rendering fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having issues rendering my Portfolio & Resume components.

I think the issue may be react-router related.

Here is my appjs file:

```
import React from 'react';

import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile'
import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer'
import Portfolio from './pages/Portfolio/Portfolio'
import Resume from './pages/Resume/Resume'

import {
  Button,
  Form,
  FormControl,
  Nav,
  NavLink, 
  NavDropdown,
} from 'react-bootstrap';




import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, } from 'react-router-dom'

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Container className={'top_60'}>                          
      {/* *Container adds space on both edges or sides of the page* */}
      {/* Profile.js line 36 */}
      <Grid container spacing={7}>
        <Grid item xs={12}
                   sm={12} 
                   md={4} 
                   lg={3}>
          <Profile/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs>


          <Router>
            <Header />
            <Switch>
              <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/" />
              <Route path="/portfolio">
                <Portfolio />
              </Route>

              <Route path="/">
                <Resume />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Router>

          <Footer />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Resume & Portfolio component code as of right now:

1.Resumejs

```
import React from 'react'

const Resume = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Resume Page
        </div>
    )
}

export default Resume
```

2.Portfoliojs

```
import React from 'react'

const Portfolio = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Portfolio Page
        </div>
    )
}

export default Portfolio
```

I'm not getting any errors but the Portfolio & Resume components are both not rendering on the page.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Switch>` renders the first child that matches the location, in your case `<Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/" />` is being rendered.

Comment: Yes I remember reading on this , I see what the issue is now, by simply having the <Nav.Link> come after the <Route>s the issue seems to be solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Placing the Nav AFTER the Routes, within the Switch,

```
         <Route path="/portfolio">
            <Portfolio />
          </Route>
          
          <Route path="/">
            <Resume />
          </Route>

          <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/" />
```

within the appjs file , seems to solve this issue.